# Can't set header preference icon via ?attr

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have created preference-headers.xml. I want to set header icon via `?attr`, but it doesn't show the icon.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<header
    android:fragment="com.armsoft.mtrade.activities.PreferencesActivity$PrefsAboutFragment"
    android:icon="?attr/menuIconAbout"
    android:title="@string/about" />

</preference-headers>
```

Comment: do elaborate the meaning of doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved the problem with a mixture of headers.xml and Changing the icon.

```
public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
    this.loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers, target);
    // search for the current header by comparing the titelRes Ids
    for (Header header : target) {
        if (header.titleRes == R.string.pref_style_title) {
            int themeDependIcon = ... //load the needed icon
            header.iconRes = themeDependIcon ;
            break;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) It solved the problem :) It seems that the solution is possible only through code(not xml).

Comment: Thanks. Please vote for the [issue #53457](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53457). (You too, please @android_dev)

Comment: where does this code go?
[update] Found it. In your PreferenceActivity's children class. +1. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem with header icons for multiple themes.

The only way is to generate headers in code...

```
@Override
public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
    final TypedArray a = getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(R.style.<YourTheme>, new int[] = { R.attr.icon1, R.attr.icon2});
    final Header h1 = new Header();
    h1.title = "title 1";
    h1.iconRes = a.getResourceId(0, 0);
    h1.fragment = "<your_fragment_path>";
    h1.fragmentArguments = new Bundle();
    h1.fragmentArguments.putString("id", "fragment1");
    final Header h2 = new Header();
    h2.title = "title 2";
    h2.iconRes = a.getResourceId(1, 0);
    h2.fragment = "<your_fragment_path>";
    h2.fragmentArguments = new Bundle();
    h2.fragmentArguments.putString("id", "fragment2");
    target.add(h1);
    target.add(h2);
    a.recycle();
}
```

Comment: what is the `a` variable ?